# Openshift pip uninstall old packages versions

Tags: pip, permission-denied, openshift

There are some bugs in `django-registration0.8`, that's why it installed 0.9 version manually throw ssh and also places newer version of `registration` directly near my scripts (under registration folder). However, django still users an old version. I'm trying to `source ..\virtaulenv` and then `pip uninstall` that package, but get `Permission denied` error.

What would you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

That should have worked.  Here's a forum thread that walks through a quick example of uninstalling django (fist comment):  https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/socjalregistration

If it's still failing, can you post your steps to reproduce the error and the error itself?  Feel free to use the forums, or follow up here.